# "Already up-to-date" and "Run 'yarn' to install missing dependencies"?

Tags: npm, ember.js, yarnpkg

I've got a bit of a weird situation where "*ember s*" reports "*Missing yarn packages*" followed by a list of missing packages (two of them) and then "*Run 'yarn' to install missing dependencies*".

However when I run '*yarn*' I get the message "*success Already up-to-date*" .

Any ideas how to get out of this circle ?

---

There's something I did immediately before this started which I guess is the source of my problem

**Getting rid of an Add-on**

I had installed an Ember Add-on which had generated problems so I decided to get rid of it . To do that I did the following :

```
git push -f origin 913c2dee12b0363df0664c9c63e0443abe0adb57:foo-bar
git reset --hard 913c2dee12b0363df0664c9c63e0443abe0adb57
yarn
yarn install
yarn clean
yarn install
yarn
```

Where 913c2dee12b0363df0664c9c63e0443abe0adb57 was the last commit before the unwanted add-on was installed. I don't think there was anything wrong in doing that but now I'm wondering.

---

**Output of running Ember Server**

When I run 'ember s' I get this output ...

```
DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: foobar -> ember-cli-build-date -> ember-cli-babel

Missing yarn packages:
Package: @bower_components/jquery
  * Specified: jquery/jquery-dist#
  * Installed: (not installed)

Package: @bower_components/jstree
  * Specified: vakata/jstree#^3.3.5
  * Installed: (not installed)

Run `yarn` to install missing dependencies.



Stack Trace and Error Report: /tmp/error.dump.33c6e8c0abc9fc8abd355dc080268f9c.log
An error occurred in the constructor for ember-cli-dependency-checker at /media/mint/dev/foobar/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker
```

---

**Warning about ember-cli versions**

I don't think this is relevant but just for completeness

Running the 'yarn' results in the following appearing in the output text ...

*warning foobar@0.0.0: "dependencies" has dependency "ember-cli" with range "~3.8.1" that collides with a dependency in "devDependencies" of the same name with version "3.8"*

---

**EDIT**: OK I was able to resolve this with the help of the comment by dwenzel ...

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn
```

Although that actually led into a different issue which I'm *almost* certain was unrelated but I'll just mention it here in case it's useful to those who come after.

The execution of `yarn` initially failed with the following error ...

```
35238 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
35238 verbose stack Exit status 1
35238 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/rshea/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
35238 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
35238 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/rshea/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
35238 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
35238 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
35238 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
35239 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.5.3
35240 verbose cwd /media/mintextra/dev/ddn-build-test-temp/foobar
35241 verbose Linux 3.13.0-169-generic
35242 verbose argv "/home/rshea/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node" "/home/rshea/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm" "install"
35243 verbose node v10.15.3
35244 verbose npm  v6.4.1
35245 error code ELIFECYCLE
35246 error errno 1
35247 error node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
35247 error Exit status 1
35248 error Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
35248 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
35249 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I was able to resolve that with ...

```
npm install node-sass@latest
npm install
```

... at which point `ember s` was able to run without errors.

Comment: have you tried running `rm -rf node_modules && yarn`?

Comment: @dwenzel - thanks. I *think* this was the answer. I say "think" because I started getting a different issue after I had done what you suggested which I was eventually able to resolve by upgrading node-sass. I'll edit the question for those who come after but maybe you'd like to make your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as correct ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When yarn gets confused like this, you can usually fix things up by clearing out your node modules before installing:

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn
```

Answer (score 18):

It looks like you want to do `yarn install --check-files` to verify that the files have not been removed from node_modules. This avoids having to wipe out your node_modules file which can be time consuming.

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-check-files
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2240

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to reinstall/download all packages with:

```
yarn install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to get around this without deleting the entire `node_modules` directory was just to remove the module from `topLevelPatterns` within `node_modules/.yarn-integrity`.

Disclaimer: I don't know what the implications of this are but yarn's integrity was already questionable and it works so meh!?